# git push --mirror getting (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am working on trying to mirror a repo into a new empty one using bitbucket server. The Hooks are disabled, however on the push -mirror I am still getting pre-receive hook declined error on every branch.

What I am using

```
 git clone --mirror <url to old_repo>
 cd old_repo
 git push --mirror <url to new_repo>
```

Am curious if anyone else has had this issue using bitbucket / bash, or any insight into a work around.

Comment: When you get a "pre-receive hook declined" error, the hook itself *should* print the *reason* it's declining to do this. If it doesn't, that's a bug in the hook (which you probably can't fix since it's on bitbucket), but if it does, that message *should* explain why. Include the message in the question.

Comment: There is no reasoning on the error, So this might be an issue on bitbucket worth looking into. Thanks.